# Как обновить конкретные поля в базе данных Mongodb (Mongoose)? findOneAndUpdate()?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

В приложении использую `Mongoose`. БД находится в облаке MongoDB Atlas. В коллекции есть такой документ:

```
{
    "_id": "5fd76620e07cba4a7b34b999",
    "data": [
        {
            "title": "1",
            "url": "/one",
            "show": true
        },
        {
            "title": "2",
            "url": "/two",
            "show": true
        },
        {
            "title": "3",
            "url": "/three",
            "show": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Вопрос. Как можно перезаписать допустим значение ключа`"title": "2"` на `"title": "290"` и `"show"` изменить на `false` а поле `"url": "/two"` вообще не трогать?

Comment: какой код используете сейчас для обновления полей?

Comment: Вопрос решил уже. Код нужен вам?

Comment: Опубликуйте в ответ и отметьте его, как верный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решен. Ниже код который решил мою задачу.

```
const data = await Test.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    _id: '5fd76620e07cba4a7b34b999',
    data: { $elemMatch: { url: '/two' } }
  },
  {
    $set: { ['data.$.title']: 'someValue' }
  },
  {
    new: true
  }
);
```